# python u'\u00b0' returns u'\xb0'. Why?

Tags: python, unicode, character-encoding, python-2.x, string-literals

I use python 2.7.10.

On dealing with character encoding, and after reading a lot of stack-overflow etc. etc. on the subject, I encountered this behaviour which looks strange to me. Python interpreter input

```
>>>u'\u00b0'
```

results in the following output:

```
u'\xb0'
```

I could repeat this behaviour using a dos window, the idle console, and the wing-ide python shell.

My assumptions (correct me if I am wrong):
The "degree symbol" has unicode 0x00b0, utf-8 code 0xc2b0, latin-1 code 0xb0.
Python doc say, a string literal with u-prefix is encoded using unicode.

Question: Why is the result converted to a unicode-string-literal with a byte-escape-sequence which matches the latin-1 encoding, instead of persisting the unicode escape sequence ?

Thanks in advance for any help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Python uses some rules for determining what to output from `repr` for each character. The rule for Unicode character codepoints in the 0x0080 to 0x00ff range is to use the sequence `\xdd` where `dd` is the hex code, at least in Python 2. There's no way to change it. In Python 3, all printable characters will be displayed without converting to a hex code.

As for why it looks like Latin-1 encoding, it's because Unicode started with Latin-1 as the base. All the codepoints up to 0xff match their Latin-1 counterpart.